# Assembly.Load throws FileNotFoundException on an assembly created through Roslyn with Added References

Tags: c#, reflection, roslyn

I have a problem loading an assembly (from a memory stream) that was emitted from Roslyn compilation.

While trying to load the assembly i'm getting a FileNotFound Exception `RazorLight, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`.

In the compilation ExternalReferences there is 261 items which includes `C:\Users\favishg\source\repos\Empeon_Reports\Reports\bin\Debug\net461\RazorLight.dll`, so i assume that the roslyn compiler knows were to find this assembly, but it still gives this file not found exception.

**More details**: i'm dynamically loading a *Sample.dll* (late binding), this dll is using RazorLight to compile a *schtml* Template, in order for RazorLight to know about the *Sample.dll* and it's type's i needed to add MetadataReferences to the *Sample.dll* which worked fine, but i still got a FileNotFound Exception.

To debug it i downloaded the RazorLight source code and it seems that the exception is when trying to get `assembly.GetCustomAttribute<RazorLightTemplateAttribute>()` from the Roslyn compiled assembly.

**Code**
Report reunner (*Sample.dll*)

```
MetadataReference metadata =MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(PayrollReport);
MetadataReference metadataRazor=MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(RazorLight);

IRazorLightEngine engine;

engine = new RazorLightEngineBuilder()
    .AddMetadataReferences(metadata, metadataRazor)
    .UseFilesystemProject(templatePath)
    .UseMemoryCachingProvider()
    .Build();

PayrollSummary payrollSummary = repo.GetPayrollData();

return await engine.CompileRenderAsync("Report.cshtml", payrollSummary);
```

Call the *sample.dll* dynamically

```
Assembly asmPayroll = Assembly.LoadFrom(ParollReportDll);

//Get the correct type from dll..

IHardcodedReport rpt = (IHardcodedReport)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
string html = await rpt.GetReportHtmlAsync(bundle);
```

Comment: You need RazorLight.dll to get the code built, but *also* need it when you run it.  The CLR has no hope to find it in that directory.  What you are going to do about it is not obvious, AppDomain.AssemblyResolve maybe.

Comment: Thank You!, I didn't know of this event, This was the solution, If you'll right it as an answer i'll accept it.